# Is ordered initialization a requirement for dependency injection generalizations/frameworks?

Tags: spring, scala, guice

I've barely used a well-known DI framework as I come to Scala from C# but I've read about them and have recently become aware of the [cake pattern](http://jonasboner.com/2008/10/06/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/) in Scala.

However, as noted in the link, the cake pattern doesn't let us control the order in which components are initialized.

To me, this only matters if the components require each-other when initializing, which seems like a bit of a design flaw  :)

What are the cases in which ordered initialization is required and can not be resolved by having a separate component context responsible for initialization?

Comment: Good question. I think it belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ though. You can close it and migrate it there.

Comment: Why would this be for programmers.stackexchange.com? It is a simple software design question. Not so simple to answer though.

Comment: Because it is a question about design patterns and it is not tied to a specific framework and it is not a specific programming problem. Compare http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq?mnu=1 withhttp://stackoverflow.com/faq on what questions to ask where. I just thought it fit better at the programmers site.

Comment: @EmilH It's specifically about the Cake pattern in Scala - which is Scala dependent. Spring and Guice are tagged in because I'm wondering if ordered initialization justifies researching them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In his talk 'The Bakery from the BLACK LAGOON' Daniel Spiewak shows some ways to deal with that particular problem.

Slides -> https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1679797/NE%20Scala/Bakery%20from%20the%20Black%20Lagoon.pdf

Video -> http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=yLbdw06tKPQ

Taken from the talk:

You can get around the null-Pointer exceptions by using **lazy val** or **def** instead of val,
at the price of possible deadlocks.

Comment: Thx, this is a really good talk.  I was asking this question because I wanted to go bananas with cake (chocolate iced banana cake being my fave) in some of the ways Mr Spiewak's talk suggests but was worried that people might've been using DI frameworks for init triggers or something, hence the ordered initialization. Since then I've come up with cooler ideas that take cake far beyond anything DI could do.